# Windows IoT Bluetooth Dongle Orico BTA-403 (PI3)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I try to use a Bluetooth-Dongle on the PI3 with Windows IoT. In the Hardware compatibility lists from Microsoft the Orico BTA-403 is recommended. But the Dongle doesn't work.

I have installed the Dongle on Windows 10 PC and in the Dongle a LED flash. In the PI the LED is off.

How can I find and install the right driver to Windows 10 IoT?

Thanks

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead (although I myself would contact the dongle manufacturer's support). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it on the other site. http://superuser.com/questions/1121181/windows-iot-bluetooth-dongle-orico-bta-403-pi3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Release Notes from the new Insider Preview is explained, how you can take of the On-Board Bluetooth.

[Insider Preview Release Notes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/ReleaseNotesInsiderPreview)

[image]

Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's on the Windows IoT Hardware Compatible list, I don't think you need to install additional driver. It should be included with the minimum windows IoT Core though.

You can use "devcon" command to query/change the status of the device.

First you need to know the VID and PID of your dongle, one way to find out is plug it to you PC, and check out in the Device Manager,

[image]

Then plug your dongle to the Pi, and connect to Pi with SSH or PowerShell,

- Use "devcon status XXXXXX" to query the driver status.
- Use "devcon enable/disable XXXXXX" to enable/disable the device.

I'm having an incompatible BLE transceiver so you can see it has trouble.

I don't have a BTA-403 at hand, so please let me know if it's working for you.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have try your solution, but it doesn't change anything. The values by devcon status is: Name = Generic Bluetooth Adapter (Not BTA-403 or else); The device has the following problem: 10; Problem status: 0xc0000001;

Comment: In this case, I'll contact Microsoft.

Comment: @SeanStayn, Just found a similar case here, could you check if it's working for you?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ccb26cb-621d-4451-8e29-db4e306473fa/how-to-setup-bluetooth-with-orico-bta403?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: @SeanStayn, also, try using "devcon restart XXXXXX", see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help. I have buy an another Bluetooh dongle, I'll test the other dongle this evening. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The other Bluetooth dongle doesn't work, too. Both dongles have the same PID VID ID. Is that ok?